# Activity crashes on onCreate()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, oncreate, android-sqlite

I built a DB using SQLite and when I try to run my main activity file which populates the DB it crashes on onCreate. I doesn't get to load the activity. My onCreate method opens a db using getWriteableDatabase and from I just add the values className, workoutName, and id to the table I have created which execpts these values. For some reason my activity won't even load. Any ideas?

Below is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class poetry3 extends Activity {

Button next;
ClassName addName;
Preference prefs;
DBHelper1 dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.poetry3);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper1(this);
    String className = "edu.njit.hss.poetry3";
    String workoutName = "Poetry 3";
    Calendar currentDate =  Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = currentDate.getTime().toString();

    int classID = 1;


    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    //if(values.size() >  25)

    values.clear();
    values.put(DBHelper1.C_ID, classID);
    values.put(DBHelper1.C_CLASSNAME, className);
    values.put(DBHelper1.C_WORKOUT_NAME, workoutName);
    values.put(DBHelper1.C_CREATED_AT, date);
    db.insertOrThrow(DBHelper1.TABLE, null, values);



    next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Continue);
    next.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler);

}

View.OnClickListener phaseHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(next.getId() == ((Button)v).getId()){
            Intent i = new Intent(poetry3.this, poetry5.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
};

    }
```

**Here is the logcat output:**

```
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.njit.hss/edu.njit.hss.poetry3}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "at": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO history(workout_name, created at, _ID, classname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "at": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO history(workout_name, created at, _ID, classname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1444)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at edu.njit.hss.poetry3.onCreate(poetry3.java:49)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
07-21 18:57:26.628: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):     ... 11 more
07-21 18:57:26.658: WARN/ActivityManager(39):   Force finishing activity edu.njit.hss/.poetry3
```

Comment: Does it force close? If so, please post the LogCat logs of the crash.

Comment: if you want a solution, you must give your LogCat too.

Comment: I added the LogCat but it looks unreadable. Is there a way to save the LogCat output to a file in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your database's create table statement (in DBHelper1.onCreate()):

```
create table history(BaseColumns._ID int primary key, classname text workout_nametext)
```

If you are trying to reference the id in a ContentProvider (like ContactsContract, CalendarContract, etc) understand that `BaseColumns._ID` means something very different in SQL; you're also missing a comma and a space. I assume you meant:

```
create table history(_id integer primary key, classname text, workout_name text)
```

If you post the string where you create your SQLite database and I can be more specific about the syntax...

```
String table_create = "create table " + table_name + " (" + BaseColumns._ID + ...
```

**New LogCat**

To read a LogCat often you want to find the lowest "Caused by", in this case:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "at": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO history(workout_name, created at, _ID, classname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
```

This happens in poetry3.onCreate(), specifically on line 49.

Here you can see that "created at" causes the error, SQLite defines variable as one word names, perhaps you meant `created_at`? But your create statement only has three columns, so I would just remove it:

```
INSERT INTO history(_ID, classname, workout_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: String sql = "create table " + TABLE + "(" + C_ID + " int primary key, " +
  C_CLASSNAME + " text, " + C_WORKOUT_NAME + " text)";

Comment: I also added the new LogCat output. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: My new string looks like this but it says I do not have column created_at?  String sql = "create table " + TABLE + "(" + C_ID + " int primary key, " +
  C_CLASSNAME + " text, " + C_CREATED_AT + " int, " + C_WORKOUT_NAME + " text)";

Comment: If you change your table's create String you also need to inform the database that this has changed, it won't check automatically. The easiest way to do this is incrementing your `Database_Version` in your OpenHelper class' constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the error:

```
07-21 18:39:32.788: ERROR/Database(507): Failure 1 (near ".": syntax error) on 0x1e0058 when preparing 'create table history(BaseColumns._ID int primary key, classname text workout_nametext)'.
```

You need a space and a comma: "classname text, workout_name text".

Comment: Thanks for your help. Someone else mentioned that and I made the changes and posted the new LogCat output